# How to set different Compass configuration options for environments in Broccoli?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, compass, broccolijs

I'm currently using the [ember-cli-broccoli-compass](https://github.com/quaertym/ember-cli-compass-compiler) plugin for compiling my SASS. However I'm having trouble being able to assign the HTTP path for image assets in the stylesheets for different environments. This is what I have so far:

var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

```
var app = new EmberApp(
{
    compassOptions: 
    {
        httpPath: 'http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/alua/',
        generatedImagesPath: 'http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/alua/'
    }
});
```

When building the application for production (`ember build -prod`), it prepends the correct S3 path for the image assets in the stylesheets. However when running the application with `ember server --proxy http://localhost:3000` the assets are built using the S3 path and not the local desired path of *http://localhost:4200*

**How do I have environment specific Compass options for the httpPath when building image asset paths?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `EmberApp.env()` you can get the current environment. For instance:

Running `ember build` returns `"development"` and `ember build -prod` returns `"production"`.

So in the worst scenario, where an addon doesn't provider options by environment, you are able to do this:

```
var env = EmberApp.env();
var compassOptions;

if (env === 'development') {
  compassOptions = your dev options;
} else if (env === 'test') {
  compassOptions = your test options;
} else if (env === 'production') {
  compassOptions = your production options;
}

var app = new EmberApp({
  compassOptions: compassOptions
});

module.exports = app.toTree();
```

I hope it helps